# It is about validation of form

Tags: javascript, html, css

**Below is the code for basic user registration form but it is not validating the form... Please can anyone tell me where is the problem. Except validation remaining code is working. Please tell me what to do for it*

```js
function validateForm()
{

  var fName = document.forms["myForm"]["fName"].value;
  var lName = document.forms["myForm"]["lName"].value; 
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var username = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
  var pwd = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
  var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  var mobile = document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;

  var emailreg = /^[\w._-]+[+]?[\w._-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
  var usernamereg = /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9])$/;
  var pwdreg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[!#$%&? "])$/;

  if(fName!="" && lName!="" && email!="" && username!="" && pwd!="" && 
 password!="" && mobile!="")
  {
      if(email.match(emailreg))
      {
          if(username.match(usernamereg))
          {
              if(pwd.match(pwdreg))
              {
                  if(pwd.match(password))
                  {
                      alert("You are Successfully Registered");
                      return true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      alert("Both Password do not match");
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  alert("Enter valid Password");
                  return false;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Enter valid username");
              return false;
          }
      }
      else 
      {
          alert("Enter a valid Email");
          return false;
      }
  }
    else
    {
        alert("All Fields are required");
        return false;
    }

}
```

```css
  #outer
  {
    height:650px;
    width:1350px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-image:url("image.jpeg");
    color:white;
    font-size:22px;
  }
  #form
  {
    height:500px;
    width:220px;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin-left:850px;
    margin-top:70px;
    background-color:black;
  }
  .a
  {
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
  }
  .b
  {
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:aqua;
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div id="outer">
  <center><h2> Registration Form</h2></center>
    <div id="form">     
        <form name="myForm" action="register.php" onsubmit="return 
    validateForm()" method="POST">

          <input class="a" type="text" name="fName" placeholder="Enter your 
       first name"/>
          <input class="a" type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Enter your 
         last name"/>
          <input class="a" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your 
         email"/>
          <input class="a" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Select 
       your username"/>
          <input class="a" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter 
         your password"/>
          <input class="a" type="password" name="password" 
         placeholder="Confirm your password"/>
          <input class="a" type="number" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter 
      your mobile no"/>
          <input class="b" type="Submit" value="REGISTER"/ name="register">

        </form>
        </div>
        </div >

      </body> 

         </html>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question accordingly to the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) directives.

Comment: Please be sure to read the part about writing a good title in [ask]. The current title is almost useless.

Answer (score 1):

Here you made several mistake in your code.

- Make sure `onsubmit="return validateForm()"` have no any blank space before `return`
- There is a error in your regular expression

  - `var usernamereg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9])$/;` You made mistake in this. you forget to add `(` at the starting of expression after `/^`

Below is the working snippet with validation.

Check it hope it will helps you

```js
function validateForm()
{
  var fName = document.forms["myForm"]["fName"].value;
  var lName = document.forms["myForm"]["lName"].value; 
  var email = document.forms["myForm"]["email"].value;
  var username = document.forms["myForm"]["username"].value;
  var pwd = document.forms["myForm"]["pwd"].value;
  var password = document.forms["myForm"]["password"].value;
  var mobile = document.forms["myForm"]["mobile"].value;

  var emailreg = /^[\w._-]+[+]?[\w._-]+@[\w.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/;
  var usernamereg = /^([a-zA-Z0-9]+([-_\.][a-zA-Z0-9]+)*[a-zA-Z0-9])$/;
  var pwdreg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9])(?=.*[!#$%&? "])$/;

  if(fName!="" && lName!="" && email!="" && username!="" && pwd!="" && 
 password!="" && mobile!="")
  {
      if(email.match(emailreg))
      {
          if(username.match(usernamereg))
          {
              if(pwd.match(pwdreg))
              {
                  if(pwd.match(password))
                  {
                      alert("You are Successfully Registered");
                      return true;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      alert("Both Password do not match");
                      return false;
                  }
              }
              else
              {
                  alert("Enter valid Password");
                  return false;
              }
          }
          else
          {
              alert("Enter valid username");
              return false;
          }
      }
      else 
      {
          alert("Enter a valid Email");
          return false;
      }
  }
    else
    {
        alert("All Fields are required");
        return false;
    }

}
```

```css
#outer
  {
    height:650px;
    width:1350px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-image:url("image.jpeg");
    color:white;
    font-size:22px;
  }
  #form
  {
    height:500px;
    width:220px;
    opacity:0.8;
    margin-left:850px;
    margin-top:70px;
    background-color:black;
  }
  .a
  {
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
  }
  .b
  {
    height:40px;
    width:180px;
    border-radius:5px;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:20px;
    background-color:aqua;
  }
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="outer">
  <center><h2> Registration Form</h2></center>
    <div id="form">     
        <form name="myForm" action="register.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="POST">

          <input class="a" type="text" name="fName" placeholder="Enter your 
       first name"/>
          <input class="a" type="text" name="lName" placeholder="Enter your 
         last name"/>
          <input class="a" type="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter your 
         email"/>
          <input class="a" type="text" name="username" placeholder="Select 
       your username"/>
          <input class="a" type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Enter 
         your password"/>
          <input class="a" type="password" name="password" 
         placeholder="Confirm your password"/>
          <input class="a" type="number" name="mobile" placeholder="Enter 
      your mobile no"/>
          <input class="b" type="Submit" value="REGISTER"/ name="register">

        </form>
        </div>
        </div >

      </body>
```